# Odd framerate issues with html 5 canvas and css animations

Tags: performance, canvas, css-animations

I'm making a 2d tile level editor (you click a tile on the loaded spritesheet and then can draw it to the main area). Although it performs fine on desktop the mobile performance is *staggeringly* slow, so I've been testing out various perf tweaks. Monitoring the results with framerate monitor from chrome dev tools (desktop), I noticed something I don't understand. When I click on the menu icon and the overlay menu pops out (visible on the left in the screenshot, uses css transform:translate for the animation) the frame rate skyrockets up to about the monitor refresh sync rate, even when drawing the canvas.

If I haven't touched the menu icon, the framrate is about 40fps on idle and ~15fps when drawing the canvas, but simply triggering the menu animation eliminates the framerate drop. It also seems to have a lasting effect, the idle framerate of 40fps no longer drops on repaints when the menu is closed, and when the menu is open the framerate stays up near 60fps.

So the question is twofold: *why* does triggering this css animation have such a HUGE effect on canvas drawing perf (15fps vs 60), and is there any way to force a consistent 60fps without having the menu open all the time?

PS* The visibility of the menu is irrelevant, leaving it on the page makes no difference but animating it in seems to affect the framerate greatly. The menu has the 'null transform hack' applied because it was triggering a repaint of the canvas it overlays, but removing only drops the fps a little at each stage of the process, the relative performance of the different states of the program are similar.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's hard to say anything here as we have not much clues... Have you noticed this behavior with many mobile browsers ? If so, it's probably a side effect on your handlers. If not, it may be related to the browser platform implementation although I really doubt it. It could also be a side effect from the library you use to animate elements (jQuery ?). There may be various pitfall here. You may want to monitor your js execution to find the time consuming calls as a first clue. Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just using css transforms for the animation, no jQuery. I'm not seeing anything in devtools to indicate a mem leak.

Comment: I was not talking about memory leak but simply time consuming calls.
And strictly, a "memory leak" can't happen in javascript because you don't allocate/deallocate memory yourself. But you are probably talking about references never being released to the GC.

Comment: You are correct. But no, none of the logic (including the VM logic like paint/reflow) is taking longer than about 5ms according to dev tools...at least on desktop

Comment: Try to check "Show paing rectangles" in the Rendering tab of Chrome devtools and see if menu animation provokes complete canvas redrawing.
Another test would be to reduce the canvas size and see it you get much higher FPS - that would (probably) mean that the canvas is redrawn completely on each menu-animation step.

Comment: Already did. That's why I applied the null transform hack to the menu (it was triggering a canvas repaint) put the presence (or lack) of the null transform didn't impact perf greatly (noticeably, but not greatly)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has this thing where upon using a css transformation it enables hardware acceleration.

It would be easy to verify it by moving the menu position with js instead of using css tranformation.

Regarding the second part of the question, if that's the case, a hidden or off-screen transformation should have the same effect.

Comment: The canvas element is accelerated by default, has been for a long time. Although this answer is not sufficient for me to accept as is, +1 for the idea of trying an off-screen animation to see if it has the same effect.

Comment: Have you tried to perform the menu animation with js instead of css ?

Comment: If by 'js' you mean just altering the css positioning directly via the DOM element's style object rather than adding a class that uses transform: translate, then yes I've tried that. *Kills* the framerate (~10 FPS)

Comment: What does chrome://gpu has about canvas ? Is anything interesting under "problems detected" ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Canvas, compositing both accelerated. GPU rasterization is off (currently true for all non-android platforms)